# Multiple value to a variable

Tags: python, variables

```
naphomokozok = open("naphomokozo.txt", "r")
naphomokozo = naphomokozok.read()
bnyuszik = open("bnyuszi.txt", "r")
bnyuszi = bnyuszik.read()
rezik = open('result.txt', "r")
rezi = rezik.read()
frozenagy = open('frozen.txt', "r")
frozen = frozenagy.read()
bingfotik = open('fotel.txt', "r")
bingfoti = bingfotik.read()

def main():
    ismetles = easygui.integerbox( "Ismétlés szám: ", "Ismi", 0, 0, 61 )
    ar = easygui.integerbox("Ár: ", "Árrrr", 0,0,999999999)
    z = 0
    t = 0
    while t in range(ismetles):
        pass
        clipboard.copy(kerdes)



with keyboard.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.backspace:
            break
        else:
            if event.key == keyboard.Key.shift:
                uzi = msg ="Richardo varázsdoboza"
                cimm = title = "Válasssz"
                valaszok = choices = ["Nyuszi", "Homokozó","Naptetős hom.", "Autós ágy", "Nyuszi ágy", "Frozen ágy", "Bing fotel"]
                kep = image = "icons/kn.png"
                kerdes = easygui.buttonbox(uzi,cimm ,valaszok,kep)

                elif kerdes == "Autós ágy":
                    autosagy

                elif kerdes == "Nyuszi ágy":
                    nyusziagy

                elif kerdes == "Frozen ágy":
                    frozen

                elif kerdes == "Bing fotel":
                    bingfoti

                main()
```

My question is how can the "kerdes" get the chosen value?
It always get only the string what it equals not the variable :(
Before this variaton they were functions but this is a shorter way just dont know how to work around it.
Thanks for any help

Comment: what do you mean by `kerdes` getting the variable?

Comment: so `kerdes` has to be the choosen one for e.g. if kerdes == "Frozen ágy" then in`clipboard.copy(kerdes)` it needs to copy the `frozen = frozenagy.read()`

Comment: i still don't get what you're trying to say. What does `clipboard.copy(kerdes)` have to do with `frozen`?

Comment: frozen have a whole txt of things to copy and that what I need to copy but it can change based on the kerdes == value

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your post has indentation problems or there is `if` instead of `elif`.
Secondly the `keyboard` module has no `Events` attribute(or probably you're using some different module).

Thirdly, as far as what ive understood, you need to specify what clipboard has to copy. So you can just call the `main` with giving specific arguments according to your conditional statements. Here's a way you can get idea from, to start implementing your program:

Replace `main` function with:

```
def main(argument):
    ismetles = easygui.integerbox( "Ismétlés szám: ", "Ismi", 0, 0, 61 )
    ar = easygui.integerbox("Ár: ", "Árrrr", 0,0,999999999)
    z = 0
    t = 0
    while t in range(ismetles):
        pass
        clipboard.copy(argument) # <--- passed argument, here the string it needs to copy
```

And in the conditional statements:

```
if kerdes == "Autós ágy":
    main(autosagy)

elif kerdes == "Nyuszi ágy":
    main(nyusziagy)

elif kerdes == "Frozen ágy":
    main(frozen)

elif kerdes == "Bing fotel":
    main(bingfoti)
```

And remove the last `main()` call.

Lastly, don't forget to close the opened files by:

`file_obj.close()` .